# How to Properly Register a BroadcastReceiver for In-App Purchases in the Manifest File in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, billing, in-app

I want to enable in-app purchases on an Android App using Google Play In-App billing API 3. The TrivialDrive example application that Google released contains the following section of Java code:

```
// Important: Dynamically register for broadcast messages about updated purchases.
// We register the receiver here instead of as a <receiver> in the Manifest
// because we always call getPurchases() at startup, so therefore we can ignore
// any broadcasts sent while the app isn't running.
// Note: registering this listener in an Activity is a bad idea, but is done here
// because this is a SAMPLE. Regardless, the receiver must be registered after
// IabHelper is setup, but before first call to getPurchases().
mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(UpgradeActivity.this);
IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);
```

This is all well and good. However, I have yet to see a proper example of how one would register the listener in the AndroidManifest.xml file or how to reference the registered listener in Java code. I have seen other examples of registered listeners that do not pertain to in-ap billing, but not one *specifically* designed for in-app billing. How would I do so?

I assume, perhaps incorrectly, that the manifest part would look something like this:

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- VERY IMPORTANT! Don't forget this permission, or in-app billing won't work. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Platform.AppCompat">

    <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Here is the relevant part. -->
    <receiver android:name="package.path.to.IabBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.SOME_UNKNOWN_PERMISSION">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SOME_UNKNOWN_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Place activities here. -->
</application>
```

I don't know what the Java code for the listener that is registered in the manifest would look like.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should to create a receiver

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Util.mBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and create the class:

```
public class mBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
}
```

}

don't forget the permissions:

```
    <permission
    android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am trying this out now. I had to hunt down the source code for the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. However, in that package, there is a reference to a class called Task that I cannot find, and it won't compile without it. Where can I find the Task Class? It is referenced in AbstractQueryController and CacheQueryController.

Comment: So far, I have imported parse, bolt, okhttp, and okio frameworks in order to get the above code to work, but there are still broken dependencies, and it won't compile. Is there not a better way to do this that does not require countless imports?